# jquery,ajax,spring,hibernate,struts2 does not call the servlet

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, hibernate, struts2

I'm developing a web page for checking the user availability using struts2, jquery, ajax. It is working fine. After I integrated the same page using spring, hibernate, struts2, it stopped working. Don't know what I have done incorrectly.

My `SpringConfiguration.xml` code is

```
<bean id="chkuserdao" class="com.dao.DaoClass">
  <property name="sessionfactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="chkuser" class="com.action.check" >
  <property name="chkuserdao" ref="chkuserdao"></property>
</bean>
```

My `web.xml` is

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ex1</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class> com.action.check </servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ex1</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/check</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`check.java` is

```
List a=new ArrayList();
String uname = request.getParameter("uname");
a=chkuserdao.getUserName(uname);

if (a.size()<=0) 
{
    out.println("<font color=green><b>"+uname+"</b> is avaliable");
}
```

My JSP is

```
 <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(".uname").change(function(){
 var uname = $(this).val();
 if(uname.length > 3){
 $(".status").html("<img src='images/loading.gif'><font color=gray> Checking  
 availability...</font>");
 $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "/check",
 data: "uname="+ uname,
 success: function(msg){
 $(".status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){
 $(".status").html(msg);
 });}});}
 else{
 $(".status").html("<font color=red>username shold be more than<b>3</b> chars</font>");
 }});});
 </script>
```

Comment: What stopped working? What are the errors that you see? Which part breaks?

Comment: i don't know may be it spring or hibernate? but it doesn't show any error,any exception

Comment: Why are you using a Servlet instead of an Action, if you are using Struts2 ????

Comment: i don't know how to send the value from action class to ajax function.that is why i'm using servlet